# FederatedPrincipal with multiples Actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm trying to create a `FederatedPrincipal` in **aws-cdk** with multiple `Action` as shown below:

[image]

Currently, I'm doing this (as shown below) in c#

```cs
new FederatedPrincipal("cognito-identity.amazonaws.com", new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "ForAnyValue:StringLike", new Dictionary<string,string> { ["cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr"] = "authenticated" } },
    { "StringEquals", new Dictionary<string,string> { ["cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud"] = cfn_identitypool.Ref } }
}, "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity");
```

How do I add the 2nd action - `sts:TagSession`?

Comment: Not really a C# guy, but this example of creating a `new federatedPrincipal` seemed like a clearer approach to using that class. Maybe it will give you some ideas? https://github.com/JSystemsTech/FederatedWebSample/blob/7e3e50b66ffeaba2154101b1149181a57b8cdcb2/FederatedAuthNAuthZ/Principal/FederatedPrincipal.cs#L19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible using high-level constructs. See this still open issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6699

TL;DR

The `IPrincipal` requires `assumeRoleAction` to be a string. But what you need is an array. It looks like it's been put on-hold because it means a BC-breaking change that the team does not want to introduce.

What I ended up with, is to use a low-level construct `CfnRole`. I use TypeScript but it should be straightforward to port it to C#.

```js
const authenticatedRole = new iam.CfnRole(this, 'AuthenticatedRole', {
    assumeRolePolicyDocument: {
        'Statement': [{
            'Effect': iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            'Action': ['sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity', 'sts:TagSession'],
            'Condition': {
                'StringEquals': {
                    'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud': identityPool.getAtt('Ref')
                },
                'ForAnyValue:StringLike': {
                    'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr': 'authenticated'
                }
            },
            'Principal': {
                'Federated': 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com'
            }
        }]
    }
});

const roleAttachment = new cognito.CfnIdentityPoolRoleAttachment(this, 'RoleAttachment', {
    identityPoolId: identityPool.getAtt('Ref').toString(),
    roles: {
        'authenticated': authenticatedRole.getAtt('Arn'),
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the The `withSessionTags` method of the `PrincipalBase` class to address this issue, as described [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/17689) and documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/dotnet/api/Amazon.CDK.AWS.IAM.PrincipalBase.html#Amazon_CDK_AWS_IAM_PrincipalBase_WithSessionTags)